# Command line utility to retrieve password, that has no echo back

Tags: bash, input

Bash builtin read command doesn't seem to support it, now I need to let user input a password while no echo should be displayed, what tool can I use?

Comment: `help read|grep echo`: "`-s` do not echo input coming from a terminal"

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully This `-s` extension of `read` is [not standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html). You may not be able to use it on any Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
stty -echo
IFS= read -p 'Enter password: ' -r password
stty echo
printf '\nPassword entered: %s\n' "$password"
```

- `stty -echo` turns off the terminal echo, which is the display you're talking about;
- `IFS=` is necessary to preserve whitespace in the password;
- `read -r` turns off backslash interpretation.

In `bash` you can also use `read -s`, but this feature isn't standard across shells.